# Dynamic Listview Layout in Windows Phone App 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows Phone App Development. I am showing list of some items in listview. It's working perfect for me but when the issue is with design. how can i set dynamic width of my listview. i.e. if i open my app in different resolution & mode, it should be in full width.

If i give fix width to my listview, it is not showing properly in all resolutions & mode. i am aware with * sizing but when i give * sizing, it is giving me error in App.g.i.cs file. On this statement

if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Please advise.

Comment: Where do you put * ? `Width` or `Length` only support Numbers. The ListView generally should be inside your Page->Grid and should scale automatically.

Comment: yes it is in Page->Grid. I have place multiple StackPanel inside my Listview. I am giving * width to my StackPanel

Comment: @malte can you please help me on this ? it's urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the items of a ListView take the full available width, set the item container style as follows:

```XAML
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

To layout list view items like you wanted in the comment, you can use a Grid:

```XAML
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      ... put your controls in the appropriate grid cells
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for advise. Basically, i need to format my listview with 3 columns, all with different width. My first & last column width is fix. Middle column width should be adjust as per available space. Can you please advise on this ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3683028 I added an example in my answer